# How do i update android SDK to 26.1.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-sdk-manager

When I try to build an APK with Unity, I get this error:

> SDK tool Version 25.2.5<26.1.1

I even updated using SDK manager, but still, I keep getting this error. On the SDK manager, I can't find the 26.1.1 update.

How do I fix this?

[image: SKD]

Answer (score 1):

I used to get the same error, The following solved my problem:

- Create a new folder in C Drive and name it as sdk.
- Unzip the sdk file in this folder.
- Goto CMD (Run as administrator)
- Now type the following codes one at a time (type one code and hit enter)

```
 cd..
 cd..
 cd sdk
 cd tools
 cd bin
 sdkmanager --sdk_root=C:\sdk\tools\bin --list # (copy/paste this code).
 sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.0" # (you can replace the 27.0.0 with any available version from the list).
```

- You will be asked yes/no, type y and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Adnroid sdk path in Unity to the newest version of the SDK.

Comment: If you are using the NDK as well... do the same

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure you have the latest SDK version installed. You can do this in Android Studio by selecting Configure->Manage SDK when it  first opens up.

In Unity->Build Settings->Player Settings.Then in the Inspector->Other Settings->Target API Level.

For NDK just download, unzip, and browse to the folder when prompted by Unity during your build.

Comment: Target API level is set to automatic. I can't find any SDK option in android studio. I am using SDK manager to update SDK

Comment: Go to this [site](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools) and download the latest tools, the version you want is the latest one at the very top. Let me know if this works and I can update my answer.